# javascript to print a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I got this code from this site to print a div:

```
    function printData()
{
   var divToPrint=document.getElementById("printTable");
   newWin= window.open("");
   newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
   newWin.print();

   newWin.close();
}

$('button').on('click',function(){
printData();
})
```

How to add css code to this javascript to apply to a table with id='table' ?

```
table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align:justify;
}

th {
    background-color: #7a7878;
    text-align:center
}
```

Comment: I was also thinking CSS would be a good way to control styling for the printed page.  When you add the stylesheet line, you might try temporarily removing everything from the table.css file to see if your page loads.  If it does, you know there's something in your CSS that's throwing things off.  Also, instead of writing data to the HTML page, temporarily hard-code something, like "This is a test.  HTML goes here."

Comment: Okay, I get it. But can you see the edit question and help me with codes ?

Comment: patience, young padawan

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/rhjv1u11/

```
 function printData()
{
   var divToPrint=document.getElementById("printTable");
   newWin= window.open("");
   newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
    var css =`table, td, th {
        border: 1px solid black;
        text-align:justify;
    }

    th {
        background-color: #7a7878;
        text-align:center
    }`;
   var div = $("<div />", {
    html: '&shy;<style>' + css + '</style>'
  }).appendTo( newWin.document.body);
   newWin.print();

   newWin.close();
}

$('button').on('click',function(){
printData();
});
```

The example just inserts a style element conatining your rules.
If the CSS you need to assign is as little as the example suggests (and does not need a lot of maintenance), this is a sufficient solution.

In case it is much more, complex CSS you should access `newWin.document.head` instead and insert a node to load external CSS. That would look somehow like this:

```
var linkElement=document.createElement("link");

linkElement.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
linkElement.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
linkElement.setAttribute("href", "your.css.file.here.css")
newWin.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(linkElement)
```

Comment: well I can see it work on http://jsfiddle.net/rhjv1u11/1/   ... maybee your error is somehwere outside this context? Also remember: not all all css data is used while printing, depending on your browser settings. Backgrounds , ie, usually get ignored. I added width 100% o the updated example to make it obvious that it works.

Comment: but it gives me a red sign on the var css line and the print button stopped, I am using dreamweaver with chrome for testing